# Replacing csv data based on conditions (python)

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file which contains data I need to delete based on certain conditions (using python). My conditions for when data needs to be deleted are:

- x < -10
- x > 10
- -1.0e-300 < x < 1.0e-300

So far I have only got as far as:

```
    with open("Infile.csv","rb") as infile,open("Outfile.csv","wb") as outfile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        for row in reader:
            row = [x.replace(x, 'NaN') if -10 <= x <= 0 else x for x in row]
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Which doesn't change anything in the output file.

The data should probably be replaced by 0 or NaN, although it doesn't really matter

Comment: `x` is a text so you can't compare it with number - even if text has only digits. You have to convert text to `int()` or `float()`.

Comment: `doesn't work` isn't a good enough description.  What does do, and what is wrong that?

Comment: @furas how do I do that for an entire csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert text to `int()` or `float()` before compare.

To delete elements when `x < -10` or `x > 10` you need:

```
[ x if -10 <= float(x) <= 10 else 'NaN' for x in row]
```

---

btw: maybe you should use module `pandas`. It could be easier.